# Calling a data frame via a string

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a list of countries such as:

```
country = ["Brazil", "Chile", "Colombia", "Mexico", "Panama", "Peru", "Venezuela"]
```

I created data frames using the names from the country list:

```
for c in country:
    c = pd.read_excel(str(c + ".xls"), skiprows = 1)
    c = pd.to_datetime(c.Date, infer_datetime_format=True)
    c = c[["Date", "spreads"]]
```

Now I want to be able to merge all the countries data frames using the columns date as the key. The idea is to create a loop like the following:

```
df = Brazil #this is the first dataframe, which also corresponds to the first element of the list country.

for i in range(len(country)-1):
    df = df.merge(country[i+1], on = "Date", how = "inner")
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
```

I got the error `ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'str'>`. It seems python is not calling the data frame which the name is in the country list. How can I call those data frames starting from the country list?

Thanks masters!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop doesn't modify the contents of the `country` list, so `country` is still a list of strings.

Consider building a new list of dataframes and looping over that:

```
country_dfs = []
for c in country:
    df = pd.read_excel(c + ".xls", skiprows=1)
    df = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, infer_datetime_format=True)
    df = df[["Date", "spreads"]]
    # add new dataframe to our list of dataframes
    country_dfs.append(df)
```

then to merge,

```
merged_df = country_dfs[0]
for df in country_dfs[1:]:
    merged_df = merged_df.merge(df, on='Date', how='inner')
merged_df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I got the idea but somehow I am not able to see the merged_df.